# Conditional formatting color not consistent for delta?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with 2022 vs 2023 delta (column D). I applied a conditional formatting rule to color the up or down delta symbols:

Rules are `=d2>0` then color it green // `=d2=0` then color it yellow

as you can see it's not working:

[image]

the ranges are correct:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: When apply to range is `$E:$E` then rule should start from `$D1` instead of `D2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Harun24hr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr) comments the reason of the wrong formatting is:

When you define the rule as `=D2=0` and the Applies to as `E:E` the rule manager does the following:

- Takes the first item in rule and applies to the first item to Applies to.

This means that:

| Rule | Applies to |
| --- | --- |
| D2=0 | E1 |
| D3=0 | E2 |
| D4=0 | E3 |
| D5=0 | E4 |
| D6=0 | E5 |
| D7=0 | E6 |
| D8=0 | E7 |
| ... | ... |